# how to catch when facebook entered my site for taking the link image?

Tags: facebook, image, events, try-catch

I want to report every time facebook takes the image of my site and adds it to a link
How can i catch this event?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Igy is correct in that you can check the user agent of the incoming request from the Facebook linter and handle it accordingly.  In my experience, you just need to check for the existence of the text 'facebook' in the user agent.  I haven't coded in C# in awhile, but here is a stab:

```
  protected bool isFacebook()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("facebook"))
        return true;
    return false;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isFacebook())
    {
        Response.Write("Facebook Linter Detected");
    } else {
        // Do regular page stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The request from Facebook to populate the metadata will have the user agent `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)`- detect this and log it if you want to see when someone shares content from your site on Facebook - the cache of each page is updated approx every 24 hours.

You could also detect traffic from Facebook users via the presence of facebook.com as a referrer URL (also in the request headers)

Comment: how cat i catch it?
i have iis server running 
and my code is asp, can u give a example code?

Comment: I don't program in ASP but presumably there's a request object you can request the headers from? if so, request the user agent header and check if it's facebook